# Progress Bar C# Variable

Tags: c#, progress-bar

I'm trying to get the value for a progessbar(in C#) from a variable I currently have, divided by 52, and multiplied by 100. This is the code I have, any suggestions to fix it ?

```
int value;             
value = TestP1.corAns / 52 * 100;             
ProgressBar pBar = new ProgressBar();            
pBar.Value = value;             
label2.Text = Convert.ToString(value) + "%";
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: What is TestP1.corAns? And what doesn't work? (PS You was 3 seconds earlier haha)

Comment: You need to loop it to keep updating progress bar.

Comment: what's your exact problem.

Answer (score 1):

`Value` is `int` variable and therefore `TestP1.corAns / 52` will be rounded to some integer value even if `TestP1.corAns` is a real number (`float` or `double`). Moreover, if `TestP1.corAns` is also integer you will have integer division. Ultimately the value of the `value`variable will be rounded to the biggest integer, smaller than the result of your operations, presumably to 0 since you want percents. In order to avoid that, first make sure to get real number after division and that multiply that number by 100. Use something like this:

```
double value;             
value = TestP1.corAns / 52.0 * 100.0;             
ProgressBar pBar = new ProgressBar();            
pBar.Value = (int)value;             
label2.Text = Convert.ToString(value) + "%";
```