# Get value from UIProgressBarView

Tags: ios, swift, progress-bar

I want to get the actual value from my UIProgressbarView. Here is a small example what I want to do:

```
var value = 0.0

myprogressbar.setProgress(0.5, animated: true)
value = myprogressbar.getValue()                 // This is how it works in Java

println(value)                                   // The output should be 0.5
```

How can I save the actual progress from my UIProgressBarView into my double variable?

Comment: Do you speak about `UIProgressView`? There is a `progress` property for that

Comment: Yes, sorry my fault I will edit my question

Comment: Frankie has the right solution for it, look at the answers below.

Comment: Just read the documentation. This is very simple question. You didn't put any effort on it

Comment: My fault was that I searched for UIProgressBar instead of UIProgressbarView, I've searched a long time for it.

Comment: @PascalAckermann do you speak seriously? If you just start type `UIProgress` in Xcode you will have autocomplete for `UIProgressView`, or just simple [google](https://www.google.ru/webhp?q=UIProgressBar+swift#newwindow=1&q=UIProgressBar+swift) it, the first link already have all information you need

Comment: It's OK now, I've already said it was my fault. Please let us finish this conversation because the problem is solved and this comments are not useful for someone who wants to gather know how with this question.

Comment: @PascalAckermann: It would be helpful for future readers if you use the actual class name in your question (UIProgressView, not UIProgressbarView or UIProgressbar as in your initial version).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Progress Bar C# Variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15878864/progress-bar-c-sharp-variable)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you mean `UIProgressView` then you can read the `progress` property

[Check out the class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIProgressView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIProgressView/progress)

An example:

```
    var myDouble = 0.0

    let progressBar = UIProgressView()
    progressBar.setProgress(0.50, animated: false)
    myDouble = Double(progressBar.progress)
    println("\(myDouble)")
```

Comment: That helped me! `var value: Float = 0.0` and then `value = bar.progress`

Comment: This is spelled out pretty well in the UIProgressView class reference in Xcode. It shows `var progress: Float` which tells you that progress is a read/write property.